# Download File or Video from URL (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, wget

ı tried diffrent libs to download video from url. But even one of them didnt worked.
Here is the link, that ı trying: `https://td-cdn.pw/api.php?download=tikdown.org-42500282235.mp4`

If it opened once, it directly asking to download, not like a html video. And ı want to save this video to local folder.

If you guys help me ı would be so proud :) (btw ım freaking ı try to solve it last 4 hours)

Comment: Hi Atticus, welcome to stackoverflow. What libraries did you try to use and what errors did you encounter?

Comment: Try this: import os + os.system('wget https://td-cdn.pw/api.php?download=tikdown.org-25114805688.mp4') -- In fact we dont know if you are using windows or Linux -- probably curl in windows

Comment: Hi, i used urllib, wget, and request. There is no error. Just the saved files is blank. 0 bayt. Also ı m using windows. I downloaded wget for windows also i even tried directly wget cli and it still blank.

Comment: The reason for that is your website is using cloudflare protection which detects automated requests. Either the file itself is empty or you might need to get permission of the website in other form to download the video you are trying to download.

Comment: You are talking about the headers, right? If so I'll look for it.

Comment: Have you downloaded a version of file that was not 0KB? Looks like the file is empty to me.

Comment: Yeah, just click the link and download. You will see. But in code, i cant save it. İt about 2mb

Comment: Oh wait, i renewed the link.

Comment: İt has a expiration date. Now you can try again :)

Answer (score 4):

There are two steps to getting file downloaded in Python so the process is os independant. I would recommend using inbuilt `requests` library. We use it to make requests to server and fetch content. Then we write the data into a file in next step.

```
import requests

URL = "https://td-cdn.pw/api.php?download=tikdown.org-42500282235.mp4"
FILE_TO_SAVE_AS = "myvideo.mp4" # the name you want to save file as


resp = requests.get(URL) # making requests to server

with open(FILE_TO_SAVE_AS, "wb") as f: # opening a file handler to create new file 
    f.write(resp.content) # writing content to file
```

But this is just a simple example. You can implement other features like `try/catch` blocks to catch any exceptions or use custom headers while making requests.

Comment: I tested this, and it works perfectly. No need to add a bypass for Cloudflare protection. I would add `resp.raise_for_status()` after the get request, in case the request failed for some reason. Also, a slight nitpick: the requests library is a third-party library, not a built-in library.

Comment: Also, I edited the answer slightly to change `"FILE_TO_SAVE_AS"` to `FILE_TO_SAVE_AS`, which seems to have been a mistake.

Comment: Thank you for the corrections @JackTaylor, I stand corrected about `requests` library and it was indeed a typo.

Comment: Ohh my daayss, thank you so much. I just tried too and hell yeah its worked.

Comment: @Atticus could you please mark it as an answer if it worked for you.

Comment: tried this today and it did save some file but blank screen. I did try to open with few video players

Comment: @rearThing If you tried to download using same URL as above, it seems to have been broken as the domain is not registered anymore. Try any valid link and it should work. Alternatively you can do `cat <downloaded_file_name>` in linux or `type <downloaded_file_name>` in cmd/powershell in windows to see what exactly was downloaded.